# Give access to trigger pipeline with deployment to reporters

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have omnibus ce instance.
There is a project on which a dozen developers and the same number of testers work. For testing, a dynamic environment was set up in .gitlab-ci.yaml, application test (codeception) for each push and some stage for review

.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
# deployment-dev-job:
ansible/deploy:
  # ...
  environment:
    name: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: https://${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}.domain.io
    action: start
    on_stop: ansible/delete
  when: manual

ansible/delete:
  stage: dev/review
  variables: 
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  environment:
    name: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: https://${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}.domain.io
    action: stop
  when: manual
  needs:
    - job: ansible/deploy
  script:
    - ssh ${STENDS_SERVER} sudo ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/delete.yaml --extra-vars="project_name=${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
```

It is necessary that testers be able to run a pipeline that deploys the application to a dynamic environment based on the pipeline settings, but due to the "reporter" role, they cannot run the "deployment-dev-job" pipeline job
How to ensure the rights for testers to run the pipeline?

---

Another question: how to check in the pipeline if the development environment is running to update it on the next push so that they don't have to do it manually on each push from developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either give the testers developer membership or higher in the project if you want them to be able to trigger the pipeline through the web UI or directly in GitLab in any way.

As a workaround, you can generate [project tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) (or group tokens) and provide those to your testers to be able to trigger the pipeline through the API.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
Maybe you know propper way how to check if there is started (successed) deployment/environment with the same ref-name, for somehow including in .gitlab-ci.yml